# How to plot confusion matrix in form of np.array as categorical heatmap in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh, heatmap, confusion-matrix

My data:

```py
short_labels = ["PERSON", "CITY", "COUNTRY", "O"]

cm = np.array([[0.53951528, 0.        , 0.        , 0.46048472],
               [0.06407323, 0.18077803, 0.        , 0.75514874],
               [0.06442577, 0.00560224, 0.08963585, 0.84033613],
               [       nan,        nan,        nan,        nan]])
```

I need to create figure in bokeh looking as `seaborn.heatmap(cm)` below:

[image]

**I would be extremely grateful for your help!**

Code below:

```py
colors = ["#0B486B", "#79BD9A", "#CFF09E", "#79BD9A", "#0B486B", "#79BD9A", "#CFF09E", "#79BD9A", "#0B486B"]

rand_cm_df = pd.DataFrame(rand_cm, columns=short_labels)
rand_hm = figure(title=f"Title",
                 toolbar_location=None,
                 x_range=short_labels,
                 y_range=short_labels,
                 output_backend="svg")
rand_hm.rect(source=ColumnDataSource(rand_cm_df), color=colors, width=1, height=1)
```

returns following error:

```
RuntimeError: 

Expected line_color, hatch_color and fill_color to reference fields in the supplied data source.

When a 'source' argument is passed to a glyph method, values that are sequences
(like lists or arrays) must come from references to data columns in the source.

For instance, as an example:

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=a_list, y=an_array))

    p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, ...) # pass column names and a source

Alternatively, *all* data sequences may be provided as literals as long as a
source is *not* provided:

    p.circle(x=a_list, y=an_array, ...)  # pass actual sequences and no source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were getting there. Mostly needed to transform your data around. You'll need to muck w/ the attributes some more to clean it up, but this should get you up and running.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import YlGn9

short_labels = ["PERSON", "CITY", "COUNTRY", "O"]

cm = np.array([[0.53951528, 0.        , 0.        , 0.46048472],
               [0.06407323, 0.18077803, 0.        , 0.75514874],
               [0.06442577, 0.00560224, 0.08963585, 0.84033613],
               [np.nan,     np.nan,     0.,     0.]])

cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm, index=short_labels, columns=short_labels)
cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm_df.stack(),columns=['val']).reset_index()

colors = list(YlGn9)[::-1]
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=0.0, high=1.0)

rand_hm = figure(
    title=f"Title",
    toolbar_location=None,
    x_range=short_labels,
    y_range=list(reversed(short_labels)),
    )

rand_hm.rect(
    source=cm_df,
    x='level_1',
    y='level_0',
    width=1, 
    height=1, 
    fill_color={'field':'val','transform': mapper},
    )

rand_hm.text(
    source=cm_df,
    x='level_1',
    y='level_0',
    text='val',
    text_font_size='10pt',
    x_offset=-30,
    y_offset=10
    )
    
show(rand_hm)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you help me with setting up text formatting to 2 decimals points and changing border of the boxes to other color?

Comment: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide.html